# Ending a timed loop

Tags: powershell

First off I want to say I've only been using powershell for a few weeks so forgive me if the question is fairly basic. I've looked around and can't quite seem to find anything that matches what I'm trying to do (or I'm not understanding it properly - which is probably the case).

Basically I have a function that starts a service in a loop, checking to make sure the process is in a stopped state before proceeding. This is due to a service that can take a fairly long time to stop. So far I have the below:

```
Function Start_service {
$timeout = new-timespan -seconds 60
$sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
while ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout){
    if ((Get-Service $Service).Status -eq "Stopped"){
        start-service $service
        write-host Starting $service service
    }
start-sleep -seconds 1
}
}
```

What I'm trying to add to the function is a check to see if the service is in a running state and if so exit the loop and move on. But I can't quite seem to figure that part out.

Can anyone please help explain how I can do this? Or if there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Is it just me or both `Start-Service` and `Stop-Service` blocks until the operation is completed? Stop-Service definitely does wait for the stop to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following one-liner uses timeout control for a service stop operation, but will exit as soon as the service reaches the stopped state:

```
Get-Service -Name "myservice" | % { $_.Stop(); $_.WaitForStatus([System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus]::Stopped, "00:01:00") }
```

`Get-Service` will retrieve the service, passing it down the pipeline. In the block that follows, we initiate stopping the service using `$_.Stop()` without waiting it for complete, and immediately start waiting for the service object to reach the `Stopped` state. The seconds parameter of `WaitForStatus()` controls the timeout (1 minute, in this particular case).

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me change the way I approach the script by putting the timer on the stop which simplifies the rest of the script for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break`, like in many other languages:

```
$sec = 0;
while ($true){
    $sec++;
    Write-Host $sec;
    start-sleep -seconds 1
    if ($sec -gt 3) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just expand the `while` condition:

```
while (!(Get-Service $Service | ? { $_.Status -eq 'Running' }) -and $sw.Elapsed -lt $timeout)
```

I also probably wouldn't use a `Stopwatch` here, instead just storing the start time and comparing with the current time to check the timeout.